# How many E/Z isomers are possible for vitamin A?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry, isomers

If *E*/*Z* is a type of stereoisomerism, then you should be able to use the formula $2^n,$ where $n$ is the number of stereogenic centres. How is it that there are 16 possible *E*/*Z* isomers according to the answer in my textbook, but there are no stereogenic centres in all-*trans*-retinol?

[image: Structure of all-trans-retinol]

Comment: E/Z is not about centres at all.

Comment: See [E/Z notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E%E2%80%93Z_notation)

Answer (score 5):

A molecule may include

- any [natural number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number) including zero of double bonds (and for each of them, *individually*, one can check if their configuration can be described as *E*, *Z*, or if this label is not applicable here [e.g., ethene])
- any natural number including zero of stereogenic centres (either *R*, or *S*)
- any natural number including zero of helical axes (either *P*, or *M*)

These three properties are *independent* of each other.

Answer (score 1):

The molecule contains four conjugated double bonds $\ce{C=C}$, which are all drawn in the *E* (*trans*) disposition. And there is no chiral carbon atom, so no *R* or *S* atom. But one, two, three or all of the double bonds $\ce{C=C}$ may be in the *Z* (*cis*) disposition. This produces $2^4 = 16$ different molecules which are all isomers. They are *EEEE*, *ZEEE*, *EZEE*, *EEZE*, *EEEZ*, then *EEZZ*, *EZEZ*, *EZZE*, *ZEEZ*, *ZEZE*, *ZZEE*, then *EZZZ*, *ZZZE*, *ZZEZ*, *ZEZZ*, and *ZZZZ*.